# CSP 2.0 (unsafe-inline) and Angular

Tags: angularjs, content-security-policy

If I implement CSP 2.0 on my angular app, and forbid unsafe-inline from script-src, would ng-click and other angular events work? I guess CSP will block all these.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS and Content-Security-Policy are well documented under the [ngCsp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp) directive.  Here are how the `unsafe` rules affect Angular:

> - `unsafe-eval`: this rule forbids apps to use `eval` or `Function(string)` generated functions (among other things). Angular makes use of this 
>     in the $parse service to provide a 30% increase in the speed of 
>     evaluating Angular expressions.
> - `unsafe-inline`: this rule forbids apps from inject custom styles into the document. Angular makes use of this to include some CSS
>     rules    (e.g. `ngCloak` and `ngHide`). To make these directives work when
>     a CSP    rule is blocking inline styles, you must link to the
>     `angular-csp.css` in your HTML manually.

Specifically [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) uses an AngularJS expression...

```
<ANY
  ng-click="expression">
...
</ANY>
```

...and an AngularJS [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) does not need eval.

> Angular does not use JavaScript's `eval()` to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's `$parse` service processes these expressions.